# Using Android Emulator (eclipse) fails to start the tic-tac-toe example

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to test the tic-tac-toe in eclipse. It compiles and deploys to emulator device (AVD) but no matter what version of Android I use, the application deployed says: Application Stopped. Close it. Is there any specific setting I should follow?

Note: I already setup the Eclipse environment, add libraries, etc.

Thanks!

Here is the log error:

```
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe/com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe.GameActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe.GameActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe-1, /system/lib]]
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe.GameActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe-1, /system/lib]]
01-16 01:07:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
```

Thanks Ali. Here is the manifest, but I see there is a match of class and activity.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.cast.samples.tictactoe"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: try using GenyMotion, it is heaps better.

Comment: Ad what do you see in the logs as the cause of crash?

Comment: GenyMotion does the same error. However nice emulator -thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Exception states that it didn't find your GameActivity class. Check your Manifest and see if the name given there as the launcher activity (GameActivity) matches with the class that you have in your package, check the package names, etc. The exception has nothing to do (at least the piece that you have shown) with Cast.

Comment: Thanks Ali. Here is the manifest, but I think the match is correct.

Comment: When you deploy this to a real phone, does it work? In other words, does it give you that exception only if it is run in emulator?

Comment: Ali, it was a configuration mistake of libraries. Now it doesn't give any exception in AVD or Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I solved by silly configuration. I created a libs folder and copied under GoogleCastSDKAndroid.jar (marked as Private Library). Compiled and it worked perfect!

Now, I just learned the casting function can't work because AVD runs a different IP address (in my case registered a 10.0.2.15) than my wifi segment (192.168.1.x). Therefore, the AVD can't see a chrome device.

I hope this last conclusion helps other people. The first was a mistake of configuration.